# How do I append data into a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I count each group in a DataFrame then append the group counts into a Summary DataFrame?

I'm very new to Python

I have set up an empty DataFrame

```
Counts_data=pd.DataFrame(columns=['filename','Green','Stubble','Baresoil','Stones','Shadow'])
```

I then start a For loop through images 
Inside the loop I create a DataFrame of RGBgroups.(Results predicted from the pixels RGB by a knn model)

```
df_img_pred=pd.DataFrame(knn.predict(df_img_data),columns=['RGBgroup'])
print(df_img_pred.head())
Img_counts=df_img_pred.stack().value_counts()
```

The output is

```
 RGBgroup
0  BareSoil
1   Stubble
2   Stubble
3   Stubble
4  BareSoil
BareSoil    56507
Stubble     52751
Shadow       5030
Stones       4267
Green         245
dtype: int64
```

I want to count each group and append the results into the "Counts_data" Dataframe along with the filename of image. I've tried numerous ways of filtering, counting and append but I can't get it to work.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Provide minimal data (csv) please. See [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: How do I attach a file?

Comment: you don't need to attach a file. Post a minimal text table so that we could know how's your data look like.

Comment: RGBgroup
0    Stubble
1   BareSoil
2    Stubble
3    Stubble
4   BareSoil
5   BareSoil
6   BareSoil
7    Stubble
8   BareSoil
9    Stubble
10   Stubble
11   Stubble
12   Stubble
13  BareSoil
14  BareSoil
15   Stubble
16   Stubble
17   Stubble
18   Stubble
19   Stubble
Here is the first 2 rows of data. This file only has Stubble and Baresoil, there could also be Green, Stones and Shadow. The total rows is 118800. Thanks

Comment: can you read this? I can't.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a dataframe in one go:

```
# list append is much more efficient
# than operating a dataframe
s = []
for row in stat_df:
    s.append(row)

# create a dataframe
labels = ['file1', 'file2', 'file3']
df = pd.DataFrame(s, columns=labels)
```

You may replace `stat_df` with your prediction df, and create labels accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a list, appending each new output to it, and when finished convert the list into `DataFrame`. Growing `DataFrame` is very costly operation.

If all you need is a simple count, consider using `Counter` from `collections` module.

Comment: Would you mind including some explanation or references on why growing dataframes is a costly operation?

Comment: It's about memory arrangement. Elements in columns (series) in DF have to be adjacent. So adding a row to DF is actually copying all it content.
see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31690076/creating-large-pandas-dataframes-preallocation-vs-append-vs-concat) for more.

Comment: Please show me how to do this, I'm open to any suggestions, the loop will loop through 100's of image files. I'm interested in the end result a summary file containing the all the image files with the counts of the 5 different group.